# warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type

Tags: c, const

estoy implementando la función *strchr* con el siguiente prototipo:

```
char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

y cuyo código es:

```
char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    char    *aux;
    
    aux = s;
    while (*aux != '\0' && *aux != (char) c)
    {
        aux++;
    }

    if (*aux != '\0')
        return aux;
    return NULL;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[50] = "Esto es una prueba";
    printf("%c --> %c", '#', ft_strchr(str, '#'));
    printf("%c --> %c", 's', ft_strchr(str, 's'));
}
```

con un pequeño main para probarlo.

Al ejecutar el programa me da el siguiente warning:

```
ft_strchr.c:7:9: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     aux = s;
```

Entiendo que es por trabajar con una variable constante y hacer una asignación, pero no consigo entender la cuál es la raíz del problema y cómo solucionarlo.

¿Hacer la asignación no es como hacer una "copia" del puntero *s y almacenarlo en *aux, trabajando posteriormente con la "copia"?

Comment: Cuando asigna el puntero a un const a una variable, el compilador no puede guarantizar que el valor a que punta el puntero sigue const.  Es decir, si dice *aux = '\0x00';, el valor de s tambien cambia y asi no es const.

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no iteras sobre `s`? No veo que necesites la dirección original.

Comment: Finalmente lo hice iterando sobre el propio s, pero sigo sin entenderlo bien,¿la sentencia aux = s también modifica s? ¿No se supone que es una copia, entonces no se debería ver modficado s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada, hay que entender que significa esta declaración:

```c
const char *s = "IRetro";
```

El código anterior se lo interpreta así: "`s` es un puntero a caracter constante", en otras palabras, le estás indicando al compilador: "Oye tío, `s` apunta a un caracter que es constante, su valor no debería de cambiar".

**Ejemplo:**

```c
int a = 5;
const int* pa = &a;
*pa = 1; // <- error de compilación
```

Como `pa` apunta a un entero constante, es ilegal desreferenciar el *puntero*, por esa razón esta expresión conduce a un error: `*pa = 1`, porque `pa` no puede modificar la variable `a` (no importa si `a` no fue declarada como una variable constante, la expresión sigue siendo ilegal).

Una vez sabiendo esto, es simple saber porque el compilador arroja un *warning* en esta línea:

```c
char* aux = s;
```

Vuelvo y repito: `s` es un puntero que apunta a un caracter constante, en cambio `aux` apunta a un caracter (puede modificarse, porque no hay tal restricción), por esa razón se queja el compilador, porque `aux` ahora podrá modificar el caracter al que apunte el puntero `s`.

Ahora te preguntarás, ¿realmente esto es un problema? Si ejecutamos tu código de seguro funcionará pero el código será confuso, porque primero indicas que el valor al que apunte `s` no debe modificarse y después `aux` si lo puede modificar, entonces no está claro cual es la intención del código.

De hecho, la finalidad de esta declaración:

```c
const char *s
```

Es poder indicar a los demás desarrolladores que `s` NUNCA debe de modificar el valor al que hace referencia. Esto ayuda a evitar posibles errores, ya que de esta forma el desarrollador no modificará intencionalmente (como sabrás, los programadores somos despitados) el valor al que apunte el puntero.

**Respondiendo dudas...**

> > ¿Hacer la asignación no es como hacer una "copia" del puntero *s y almacenarlo en *aux, trabajando posteriormente con la "copia"?

Por supuesto que sí.

Esta línea es simple de interpretar:

```c
aux = s;
```

Estás copiando la dirección de memoria al que apunta `s` en `aux`, al final `aux` y `s` apuntan a lo mismo. El problema de esa asignación es que `aux` puede modificar el valor al que apunte `s`. Este *warning* es simple de solucionar, anteponga el `const` en la declaración:

```c
const char* aux = s;
```

De hecho, el puntero `aux` es innecesario, lo puede eliminar y trabajar directamente con `s`.

**MUCHO OJO:** No se confunda con esta declaración:

```c
char* const s;
```

En ese caso `s` es un **puntero constante** que apunta a un caracter, esto significa que no puede modificar el contenido del puntero.

Comment: ¡WOW! Muchas gracias por esta explicación tan detallada, me ha quedado clarisimo. Muchas gracias!!